# Uncategorized BACK muscles

Tags: muscle, training, lower-back, back, body-measurements

Very often I hear the terms "middle back" as well as "lower back" aside from the traditional "Lats" and "Traps" which are defined by their actual name and not something like "side back training" for example.

[image]

If I want to train the "Rhomboids" and "Teres major" which one would be the synonym for which...is Rhomboids the "middle back" and Teres Major the "lower back" or is it the other way around? Also the "Erector Spinae"...is this a synonym or part of one of the previous muscles? And where would it fit..Middle or low back?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me that is even more complicated, since English is my second language. Anyway. If you have muscle name - use wikipedia. That is not perfect, as a source of information, however do great job as a starting point. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratus_lumborum_muscle) is example - that is part of lower back.

"Rhomboids" and "Teres major", are at top of your back - so I would say - that is upper back. Lower back / upper back is more general name, then name of particular muscle. That way you can refer to something that is more understandable. Like "I feel pain, at bottom of my back. To be more precise - at right side"... Other way is more complicated. Can you tell if pain comes from teres major, or minor? On one hand - that is obvious, on the other - they are next to each other. So I would say - "I feel discomfort at the bottom of shoulder blade".